# Restoring the original intent of the author would vandalize the Q&A

Tags: discussion, support, edits, editing-help

The Q&A at [Why do we need virtual functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2391679/5740428) is a dilemma.

The author seems to understand virtual member functions to some extent, and their confusion is mainly caused by

> But earlier in the book, when learning about basic inheritance, I was able to override base functions in derived classes without using virtual.

The original title of the question was *"Can someone explain C++ Virtual Methods?"*, which is not a great title, and [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2391679/3) changed it to *"Why do we need virtual functions in C++?"*

This new title doesn't match the intent of the author, but it went unnoticed and was never rolled back. A more accurate title which addresses this issue would be *"Why can I omit the virtual keyword on member functions in derived classes?"*. The Q&A is filled with

- good answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/2392656/5740428 which answer the wrong question and ignore the author's problem, and with
- lower quality answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431061/5740428 which correctly address the quoted problem.

### Possible Solutions

1. Reword the question text and replace it with something that makes the Q&A as a whole make sense, i.e. make the question match the answers.
   Such an edit obviously conflicts with the intent of the author and amounts to vandalization.
2. Ask a moderator to delete or relocate the answers, but such drastic changes would vandalize the Q&A as a whole. Chances are, many links to it exist already from external sources.
3. Do nothing, leaving the Q&A in a nonsensical state where most answers don't address the question that the author intended to ask.

I'm genuinely puzzled because doing anything and doing nothing seem like bad options.
My intuition is to throw the author under the bus so that the Q&A can be improved, and maybe a site moderator should make that edit, not me.

Comment: I don't see why you feel the "good" answer does not answer the OP's question. It does show how a non-virtual and virtual subclass member function differ – i.e. that one can omit virtual but what the implications of that are. This seems to answer the question, at the very least indirectly - the question was an XY problem confusing why omitting virtual seemingly worked because they did not catch the nuance of the two cases.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi because the author dedicated a paragraph of their question to asking why `virtual` isn't needed in that context, and the answer doesn't address that problem. It indirectly shows an example of `virtual` and non-`virtual` member functions being overrides, but it's still unclear why that actually works.

Comment: That's a reason to downvote the answer... Nothing more.

Comment: @Cerbrus downvoting answers that have reached 50+ upvotes on this website is useless 99% of the time.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'm not sure what question you are reading. The initial versions never asked "why virtual isn't needed in that context" or similar. They asked "So what am I missing here?" and as far as I can tell, examples showing what they may have missed seem to answer that.

Comment: If it's gotten that many upvotes, then maybe there's something to the answer. Maybe you're misreading or misunderstanding something... Not that any of that matters, you get to vote how you want to, but that doesn't include deleting useful content.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'm able to read, thank you very much. Do I have to prod you for a third time to *explain* why you feel this asks what you think it asks? It should be obvious by now that we are interpreting the question differently. The quote isn't a question, it's context of a question, so reducing the entire question to just this seems to need justification.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the first two paragraphs are just context and introductory fluff that describe the author's knowledge level. The third paragraph (quoted) is an actual problem that the author has. The last paragraph is either a genuine question *"I know there is more to virtual functions, and it seems to be important so I want to be clear on what it is exactly."*, or this is just more outro fluff.

Comment: Seeing that the majority of the question once fluff is removed is a question about the `virtual` keyword, that seems to be the most significant (possibly the only) aspect to the question.

Comment: I agree that there is a second interpretation: namely that all first three paragraphs are just describing the knowledge level of the author and that paragraph 3 is just an anecdote for something that they don't understand. Ideally the author would improve their own wording but they've never made any updates to the post.

Comment: I think the question is plenty clear: _"Why do I need `virtual` when inheritance works without it?"_ (paraphrased), and there's plenty of answers (including the accepted answer) that explain why `virtual` is sometimes necessary...

Comment: The top answer doesn't truly explain why virtual functions are necessary. It merely compares what happens with and without the usage of the `virtual` keyword. This is certainly helpful to beginners from a prescriptive sense... but it also completely avoids discussing why dynamic polymorphism behaves like that in C++ in the first place. In contrast, such dynamic behavior is the default in e.g., Python.

Answer (score 13):

1. No, we don't delete content "just because" it could be improved. There's no valid reason to delete or completely change such a highly upvoted and viewed question.
2. No, as you said, that would vandalize the entire question. Basically referring you back to point 1.
3. The least of all evils.

The question isn't great, not all answers are great, but you can't argue the Q&A hasn't been useful on this platform.

Furthermore, the question is ***old***. Rules changed, but that doesn't mean this question should suddenly be vandalized / deleted.

---

If it can't be improved, and it shouldn't be deleted, there's one more possible option:

### A historical lock.

But then you'd have to ask whether this question really needs a lock?
Considering the number of low-quality answers it's gotten, and the number of (deleted) answers it already has... Why not?

---

I did flag the question to be locked, but even that was not necessary, according to the moderator who handled the flag.

So there we are, nothing needed to be done :D

Comment: (Valuable) data preservation oriented reasoning, that will always get my vote. Lock it. Lock it real good.

Comment: I didn't say "delete the question". I said "delete the question text", i.e. rephrase the question.

Comment: @JanSchultke If it matters, this doesn't read to me as if Cerbrus is misrepresenting your position. It's quite clear to me that Cerbrus is just trying to make the point that radically changing or deleting the question (even if you didn't suggest the latter) is unwarranted in this scenario.

Comment: @Spevacus when the answer starts with *"No, we don't delete content "just because" it could be improved."* and I didn't advocate for deleting the question at all, that's a misrepresentation. Also quite frankly, if someone was insulted by my words and told me that I'm misrepresenting them, I would consider rewording my statement out of politeness. It's just a matter of polite conduct on this website.

Comment: @JanSchultke "Rewording" a question, is at some level "deleting content".  It is however, NOT deleting the question.  Yes, you did not say "delete the question", but this answer also, did not say that you said 'Delete the Question".

Comment: @StephenRauch Revision 1 simply says *"There's no valid reason to delete such a highly upvoted and viewed question."* which was a blatant misrepresentation. I never asked to delete the question. After my first comment, OP has made the language milder, but the connotation is still there. Yes, it technically doesn't misrepresent me as hard as revision 1 did, and it now has enough plausible deniability to pass. I agree with that. I still perceive the wording change as too mild, especially when OP was willing to edit their question in some way to fix their mistake.

Comment: Obviously, paragraph 1 was originally written as if I had asked for the question to be deleted completely, which I didn't. I think it's bad faith to make the same argument with the same wording when you know that it's wrong, but insert "or completely change" into it so that it *technically* could no longer be interpreted as a misrepresentation by some people.

Comment: Mate, you're gonna have to accept that the answer is not going to get edited. Please stop this.

Answer (score 6):

I see problem neither in the question post, nor in its title, nor in its top answers.

My interpretation of two paragraphs

> From what I've read (in the book and online), virtual functions are functions in the base class that you can override in derived classes.
>
> But earlier in the book, when learning about basic inheritance, I was able to override base functions in derived classes without using virtual.

is:

"I understand from the book that a `virtual` keyword is used in the base class for **allow a function to be overridden** in the derived classes. But in my experiments I was able to override a function even without using `virtual` keyword at all (even in the base class). Such possibility to override conflicts with my understanding of the `virtual` keyword. So.. where am I wrong?"

The current title "Why do we need virtual functions in C++?" perfectly fits to the above interpretation: If overriding could be achieved even without `virtual`, then why `virtual` is ever needed?

And the answers explain, that overriding of a *non-virtual* function allows to call the new function only via **pointer of the derived type**. But `virtual` keyword allows the new function to be called via **pointer of the base type**, if that pointer actually points to the object of the derived type.

So, everything seems to be good and require no intervention.

---

Concerning the answers linked in the discussion:

> good answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/2392656/5740428 which answer the wrong question and ignore the author's problem

I find that answer perfectly addressing the question asked. It explains the difference between dynamic polymorphism (with `virtual`) and overriding with a nice demonstration example.

> lower quality answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431061/5740428 which correctly address the quoted problem.

This answer addresses the problem in the question too, but seems to miss explanations about shadowing and overriding. Thus it has not a great value and a low score.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157393/5740428 is another answer which focuses somewhat on the syntactical part. (from the comments)

This answer explains a bit more about difference between "Redefining a method" and "Overriding a method", thus it has a bit more score. Or it has more score just because it has been posted 6 years before the previous answer...

Comment: If OP is struggling with their question of when to apply the `virtual` keyword and when it's optional, then the question is largely about language syntax and not about the purpose of dynamic polymorphism. I think the conclusion that you're drawing is possible, but answering a question that struggles with *"this works even if I don't use `virtual`"* with an introduction to OOP, dynamic polymorphism, and `virtual` in general is a leap.

Comment: The fact that people have left answers that interpret the topic of OP's question as anything from language syntax to OOP is evidence that OP's question is ambiguous. There clearly is a problem with ambiguity, just looking at the answers. Concluding that no intervention is required makes little sense then.

Comment: @JanSchultke: I have listed near 10 most trended answers, but the only answer which resembles a one about "language syntax" is https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431061/3440745. It has only a score of 2. Do you mean that answer when talk about ambiguity? If, say, only 10% of answers are about different problem than the one I reformulated in my post, then the problem could be not with the question itself, but with the people who provide such answers...

Comment: Jan, it's a _very_ old question that has a lot of views... That's a _magnet_ for people trying any and all angles to leech off some upvotes. ___Every___ old, high activity has a bunch of semi-relevant answers. That's not the question's problem. That's just a fact of old active questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157393/5740428 is another answer which focuses somewhat on the syntactical part. You also have to keep in mind that a lot of the answers were posted or gained popularity after the edit to the question was made, so that makes the sample biased.

Comment: The thing is that from a practical standpoint, a lot of the questions are of high quality and they address one possible interpretation of OP's question well. The issue is more about site policy and the fact that editing OP's original question to remove the ambiguity would violate author intent.

Comment: You're trying to apply _current_ site policy to a question that's __over 13 years old__... Of course it's not gonna be perfect!

Comment: Current site policy obviously applies to edits, flags, moderator actions etc. which are being made now.

Comment: _"edits, flags, moderator actions etc. which are being made now."_ There are none, on the question... At least, none that I can see, aside from some insignificant formatting changes.

Comment: I'm obviously talking about possible actions that could be taken now, since that is what the Q&A is about. And site policy applies to actions taken now.

Comment: The only action that _should_ be taken now, is a historical lock.

Comment: Okay, and current site policy applies to locking posts at this time. Point proven.

Comment: @JanSchultke: I have updated my post and have included my vision of answers which you referenced in your question and in the comments. In short: I find none of those answers to be completely "off-question". But a value of that answers differ, which by some extent is reflected by their scores.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I agree with your estimate of the quality of the answers. I wouldn't read too much into their vote count though. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431061/5740428 was posted in 2018 and based on my experience, even extremely high quality answers on old posts can be stuck on zero upvotes for months, simply because no one scrolls far enough and casts votes on new answers.

Comment: "simply because no one scrolls far enough and casts votes on new questions." - Well, at least that problem could be solved without drastic editing of the question post. It is sufficient to just ... **downvote** those late crap answers which provides a nearly no additional info comparing the already existing answers. But we are too lazy for doing such downvotes. (Me is lazy too.)